# How to loop through an array and find matches with the values in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string-matching

I have 2 sets of arrays which their value is grabbed by `data-attribute(data-product-name)`, 1 is the whole list of available item, another 1 is selected item, for selected item they are attached to a country.

```
    <!-- the item list -->
    <div class="whole_list">
      <ul>
        <li data-product-name="a">item A<button>ATTACH</button></li>
        <li data-product-name="b">item B<button>ATTACH</button></li>
        <li data-product-name="c">item C<button>ATTACH</button></li>
        <li data-product-name="d">item D<button>ATTACH</button></li>
        <li data-product-name="e">item E<button>ATTACH</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- selected item block -->
    <div class="selected_item_container"> 
      <ul class="selected_items">
        <li data-product-name="a">item A</li>
        <li data-product-name="b">item B</li>
        <li data-product-name="e">item E</li>
      </ul>
      <button class="edit_country">EDIT</button>
    </div>


    $('.edit_country').on('click', function () {
      // to grab text/string from .whole_list data-product-name
      var productName = []; // product name
      $('.whole_list li').each(function (index) {
        productName .push($(this).data('product-name'));
      });

      // to grab text/string from .selected_item_container data-product-name
      var selProductName = []; // selected product name
        $('.selected_item_container').find('[data-product-name]').each(function () {
         selProductName .push($(this).data('product-name'));
       });

      // if the string/text matches, change the button text
      $('.whole_list li').each(function (index) {
      if ($(this).data('product-name') === arrProductName[index]) {                         
        $(this).find('button').text('DETACH');
        } else {
          $(this).find('button').text('ATTACH');
        }
      });
    });
```

Ideally is when user click on edit_country button, the .whole_list already have those selected item button changed to DETACH text. I tried, but the problem is, it only change the item A & item B button, item E button no changes.

I think it got to do with the indexing mismatch. I'm not sure, please advise, thanks.

[Demo site](http://www.greysaga.com/demo/stackoverflow/country_1.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.indexOf`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) to find if a value exists in an array.
Like this:

```
arrProductName.indexOf( $(this).data('product-name') ) != -1
```

Because, using `$(this).data('product-name') === arrProductName[index]`...
If your array is like:

```
var arrProductName = ["a","c","d"];
```

`a` will be found at index `0`,
`b` will not be found,
`c` wil **NOT** be found at index `2`... It is `d`,
`d` wil **NOT** be found at index `3`... It is `undefined`,
`e` will not be found.

See it in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/KqbMwz?editors=1011).

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
$('.edit_country').on('click', function() {
  // to grab text/string from .whole_list data-product-name
  var productName = []; // product name
  $('.whole_list li').each(function(index) {
    productName.push($(this).data('product-name'));
  });

  // to grab text/string from .selected_item_container data-product-name
  var selProductName = []; // selected product name
  $('.selected_item_container').find('[data-product-name]').each(function() {
    selProductName.push($(this).data('product-name'));
  });

  $(selProductName).each(function(index) {
    $('.whole_list li[data-product-name=' + selProductName[index] + ']').find('button').text('DETACH');
  });

});
```

Comment: You saw something there. Bravo. I didn't understood the problem like this. You certainly are on the right track. But a little more explanation on your code would be great. ;)

Comment: Thank you @Louys Patrice Bessette, I'm new to stackoverflow. I'll try to give more explanation. OP wanted to identify selected li, so, 1) firstly why iterate over larger set, secondly why iterate over dom when he already has selected i value in an array. 2) Why do array maping based on index, when we can leverage power of css selectors and jquery for the same. Its more efficient, less error prone, clean and moreover, less code!.

Comment: @Grey Ooi, could you please give this a try.

Comment: I tried this 1 out too, but the same problem persist. Louys Patrice already solved the problem for me though. Thank you for the efforrt SamB. Appreciate that.

Comment: @Grey Ooi, I tried my solution and was able to get what you required. Anyways, Glad you got your answer.

Comment: @Samb, your script can find the match from the array, yes. But If i want to match the array value randomly, it won't work.